# TFS List File modified after 'Label'

Tags: tfs, label

I'm working with TFS 2008 with Continuous Build integration.

It's possible to have a list of files modified after Label applied?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as easy as you might thing.  First off, don't consider the label to be a specific point in time.  You can move a label from one version of a file to another, so the date of one given file might not be the same as the dates of the rest of the files in the build.

Instead, you probably want to go by a given date.

1. Get the start time of the build, then
2. Use the commandline TF.EXE to get the list (where the build start time is the datetime shown in version below).

   tf history /server:http://tfs:8080 "$/Project/Dev/Src" /version:D2010-06-04T00:00~T /format:detailed /noprompt /recursive

This will get a detailed list of all changes that happened since 06/04/2010 at midnight, and the current time ("T").

If you're looking to do this programmatically, let me know and I can give some guidance there.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the `history` command will only tell you files that have changed between two labels, but won't tell you files that have been added or removed.

If you want to know that then you need to use the `diff` command, e.g.

```
tf.exe diff "$/<tfs folder>" /recursive /noprompt /format:basic /version:"Llabel1~Llabel2"
```

This is equivalent to doing the following from Visual Studio 2010
[image]

**EDIT:** I've recently re-tried this using TFS2013, and it now only shows changes to files that exist in both labels, i.e. is now the same as using `history`. So either I was wrong when I first posted this, or TF.exe has been changed.